# Does clearing an image by assigning Image1.Picture := nil; cause a memory leak?

Tags: delphi, timage

I have read here http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2005/qt/cleartimage.htm that a way to clear an image from a TImage is to assign nil to `.Picture`, like this:

```
Image1.Picture := nil;
```

I just want to be sure... I guess the `Image1.Picture.loadFromFile(fileName)` will allocate some memory and simply setting it to nil, without freeing the memory, will lead to a memory leak.

Am I correct? If this is so, which is the "proper" way to unload and clear an image from a TImage?

Comment: take a look at `procedure TPicture.SetGraphic(Value: TGraphic);` in Graphics, you will find that the exisitng graphic will be freed.

Comment: I didn't know I had access to the whole source code for the VCL... Wow, you helped me discover a whole new world ;) Next time I will dig into it before posting a question. Thank you!

Comment: @bummi You should post this as an answer.

Comment: I just discovered that Image1.Picture.loadFromFile('') will clear the image. Cool. right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `TImage.Picture` setter is `TImage.SetPicture()` in the `ExtCtrls` unit, which calls `TPicture.Assign()` in the `Graphics` unit, which calls `TPicture.SetGraphic()`, which will free an existing `Graphic` before assigning a new `Graphic`.

So the usage of

```
Image1.Picture := nil;
```

Will ultimately call

```
Image1.Picture.SetGraphic(nil);
```

And will not cause any memory leak.