# Although setting TImage::Picture = NULL won't cause a memory leak, what alternatives exist that might avoid that confusion?

Tags: c++builder, timage

Despite [bummi's fine explanation of why `Image1.Picture := nil` won't cause a memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23999207/782738), I'm concerned that it may raise red-flags in the minds of new people reading my code, since its safety is counter-intuitive.  Therefore, I'd like to avoid it.  What more-intuitive alternatives exist?  Although bummi's answer was for Delphi, I'm actually more interested in C++Builder.

Comment: This is a general problem with Properties: you don't know what hooks are in place . If the syntax were `Image1.setPicture(NULL);` then there'd be no confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encapsulating the property assignment provides two advantages:

1. a single location to document the non-leakiness of it ([DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))
2. a less worrisome-looking interface to use everywhere else

e.g.:

`// Not a memory leak: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23999207/782738`
`#define ClearImage(Image) Image->Picture = NULL`

Answer (score 1):

The alternative is to use `Image->Picture->Assign(NULL);`, which is actually what `Image->Picture = NULL;` does internally.

Answer (score 0):

I've set `Image1.Visible` to `false` to cause a picture to disappear.

- Disadvantage: You'll have to restore `Visible` to `true` when you want to display the next image.
- Advantage: if you happen to want to display one particular image, but only at certain times, then toggling Visible could be more efficient than clearing and reloading.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried that the reader doesn't understand what `image.Picture := nil;` means, and you've established that that is the most straightforward way to clear an image, then add a comment stating what the property setter does.

I don't necessarily agree that it needs any change at all, though. It's well-established that property setters can have side effects, and there is no convention in Delphi that after setting a property to a specific value, that re-reading that property will return that same value. In fact, in the VCL I suspect that properties that *don't* return the same value that was just set are more common.

Either way, comment or not, I would leave the assignment using `nil` exactly as it is.